# Can MD5 from a MySQL field be used in another MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

We have an existing website written in PHP/MySQL (Joomla 1.5) where the user's passwords are stored in the TABLE using MD5. This website is going to be totally overhauled and I'm wondering if the user's passwords can simply be copied and re-created in the new MySQL TABLE and still work? Is a MD5 user's password portable to another MySQL even on a different system? Or is the encryption of MD5 on MySQL altered by some other factor? Thanks!

Comment: If MD5 wasn't portable, it would be completely useless: the whole point of a hashing algorithm is that it should always produce the same value from the same input (irrespective of platform); the drawback of MD5 is that it can produce the same values from too many different inputs

Comment: If your current system uses a salt to secure the password hashes, make sure you use the same key/function on your new website (no matter what db or programming language you use).

Comment: That's the "drawback" of any hashing algorithm - it's not even that there are "too many" - there are *infinitely* many inputs that map to a given hash value. However, algorithms like MD5, SHA1 etc are designed to make it hard to calculate a input which will yield a chosen hash.

Comment: @MarkBaker I asked because I recall that on UNIX /etc/password file passwords were encrypted and I was told it wasn't portable. I wanted to make sure MD5 is, otherwise thousands of existing user logins on this project would have to be asked to re-created their logins and I didn't want to inconvenience the users if it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @Edward Usually OS stuff that's encrypted and is not portable is because it's encrypted with a public/private key pair that's unique to the machine/user. That's how it is on Windows. But that's encryption, this is just plain hashing.

Comment: @CodeAngry OK, I see. This is hashing NOT encryption. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider upgrading the hash function as well. MD5 isn't much better than plain text.

Comment: @Edward This is **the latest fad in [PHP Password Storage^](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)** and you should use it with 7+ strength :) Just make sure you time it so it doesn't go into many seconds realm *(milliseconds is good)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MD5 is portable** as long as all involved parties *(input, salt and pepper)* are the same!

**PS**: *But MAKE SURE you backup first :)*

Comment: Yes, rsync and mysqldump are my friends. :-)